# How to delete an Operating system?

Tags: boot

After I installed Ubuntu, I  want to remove ubuntu as it has allocated 20gb space of my HDD
While my PC boots i see a choice. i want to remove that choice and use debian only

Comment: If and obviously Ubuntu and Debian 7 is installed in Different partitions then ofcourse you can remove it and use only ubuntu. I would like to know in which partition you installed both operating systems and also post the output of this command: `sudo blkid` after editing your question.

Answer (score 5):

You can use OS-Uninstaller is a small graphical tool to perform a clean and quick uninstall of any operating system (Windows, MacOS, Ubuntu, other Linux distribution..) of your computer.

To install, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install -y os-uninstaller && os-uninstaller
```

For more info, and options visit [OS-Uninstaller](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OS-Uninstaller)

<sup>Source:[Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OS-Uninstaller)</sup>

Comment: no, boot reapir not available for debian!

Comment: You un-accepted after you altered your question.  But you can get a bootable CD with OS-Uninstaller, that's independent of the OS.  See the link in my answer.  Once you click on the link it's the first option.

Comment: okay , so i accepted.

Comment: The answer I gave is 100% correct, and will work in your case, as I said.  see the link:)

Comment: i downloaded the iso file, but how coud i burn it on a usb (my cd drive does not work ...)

Comment: OOOOOOOOOOOOOOO! ITS 500 MB! its toooooo heavy. any other option?

Comment: You can try using [Unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) or [Yumi](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to uninstall ubuntu you can just start a linux livecd and run gparted.

You can now delete the ubuntu partition and set "Boot" flag on Windows' partition.

Reboot and enjoy winzozz.

P.S. Note that windows partitions will not automatically allocate linux hdd space, you need to do it manually and it's and extremely delicate operation;
If you turn the pc off while working you will LOSE ALL you got on your windows partition.